# Prompt user to input 2 numbers, and determine which is smaller. but must be done with custom function, not built in "max" func

Tags: python

i have edited the code to the following and getting more favorable results..

```
#Python program that will prompt user to enter two numbers, one at a time 
and then determine which of the two numbers is smaller.

#define functions
def find_min(first, second):
if first < second:
    return first
else:
    #second < first
    return second

#Get user input
first = int(input('Please type first number: '))
second = int(input('Please type second number: '))
def print_result(first, second):
    if first < second:
        print(first, 'is smaller than' ,second)
    else:
        #second < first
        print(second, 'is smaller than' ,first)

def main():
#Get user input
    first = int(input('Please type first number: '))
    second = int(input('Please type second number: '))


    print(print_result(first, second))
main()
```

__
i am getting the code to work now but it is printing 'None' at the end of the result. and function "print_result" is not typing the string 'is smaller than' now.

Comment: Why can't you use the built in functions to do this? If this is a homework assignment, asking us to do the work for you will teach you nothing.

Comment: yes it is a homework assignment. and im not asking anyone to do work for me. ive clearly already done work, i am trying to find someone that knows how to do something a bit more complex than just use the built in function.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you did. Except of course you didn't put parameters for the function. There is no "complex" way of doing this. You could also add an `elif` to check if the numbers are equal.

Comment: It is OK if this is homework. But you have to be very clear what it is that is giving you difficulty right now. Explain what exact part you are having trouble with, and what issues you are facing with that particular implementation.

Comment: thank you. quite simply, perhaps me being new to programming and being asked by the assignment (for reasons that baffle me) why to not use integrated functions that are aimed at simplifying things.   for starters. i have defined the function "find_min()" at the top and set up paramaters (i believe) that satisfy which input number is smaller.  I don't understand why print_result needs to be a specific function? Why not simply place print_result towards the end of the code to satisfy the desired result

Comment: "*I am trying to find someone that knows how to do something a bit more complex [..] (for reasons that baffle me) why to not use integrated functions that are aimed at simplifying things* - so you can learn to do the more complex thing, of course. And since you claim you can do it with builtins, but you can't do it like this, that's something useful to learn. [See your code on repl.it](https://repl.it/J2lm) and see the three error triangles and two warnings on the left by the line numbers (hover the mouse over them) - fix those and your code will be closer to working..

Comment: You have no loop in `find_min()`, it's just printing one of two things conditionally. However the major issue is your use of global variables without declaring them as such in your functions—by default all variables in functions are local to it and cannot be accessed by other functions. Add a `global first, second` to the beginning of both of the ones you have.

Comment: P.S. You also need to change `def print_result` to `def print_result():`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code:

1. as mentioned above you pass in no variables to the find_min function
2. you do not return a value, you print an answer

your last line should look like this:

```
print("smallest number is: {}".format(find_min(a,b))
```